# Stages of browser javascript API's standarization

Tags: javascript, browser, specifications

I want to know how process of implementing new javascript API's looks like.

From what i read, it should looks like this:

1. W3C defines specification, it passes stages from WD to REC
2. After REC version of spec is ready, browsers can implement new features.

Thing that bothers me is fact, that some new features (eg. WEB Audio API, Web RTC) are already implemented in browsers, despite W3C specifications is on WD status.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Standardization often starts from an experimental extension in some implementation. Then the standards committee works on generalizing it.

Comment: Also other implementations may copy and modify the original extension, and W3C reconciles the differences.